# My paper was under review for two days and now is 'Awaiting AE Recommendation'. What does this indicate?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I submitted a research paper to a journal. After one day the status was EA assignment pending and after two more days it was under review. But only after two days under review the status changed to “Awaiting AE Recommendation”. Can anybody please tell me what does it indicate?

Comment: Nobody by the AE knows. Maybe the reviews were quick or a reviewer declined the review. You will find out when you find out.

Comment: I don't think a decline on the reviewers part would lead to a post-review status

Answer (score 5):

Using something named Google; "Awaiting AE recommendation -> The paper received the sufficient number of reviews (usually 2) and, on their basis, AE
makes recommendation to EIC."

That is a very fast review process. Maybe the reviewer(s) had some spare time, maybe a glance at the paper was enough (although that would be odd, as an editor would normally decide a straight reject if this is what the paper calls for)

Comment: To give the OP a bit of credit, the google answer you quote seems implausible given the short time duration--as you note. Perhaps on that particular editorial management system, this means that the AE is in the process of deciding whether to desk reject the paper or to send it to review.

Comment: @Corvus The OP indicates the paper was already "under review" though only for two days.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're right -- reading comprehension fail on my part. New guess: the journal is on Beall's list? I don't know how else you get reviews back in that time span.

Comment: @Corvus I have had a paper accepted three days after submitting it. This was in a reputable (though not top) math journal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft And do you feel that it had been adequately peer reviewed in that time?

Comment: @Corvus No, the reviewer comments were pretty good and certainly indicated that they had read the paper (this was a quite short paper though).

Answer (score 3):

AE stands for "Associate Editor.""Awaiting AE recommendation" status means that the AE has collected all reviews from the reviewers who were assigned to review your manuscript and that the AE's decision for acceptance is pending.
t backed up) waiting to be sent to some reviews.

If it has been reviewed., the AE would send her/his report to the EiC (Editor in Cheif), for the final decision on accepting the manuscript for publication in the journal based on the review results and the report from the AE.

It could also perhaps be that it is waiting to be sent to reviewers, but this is probably unlikely and is my take on it, it could just be the terminology used. Most likely your paper has been reviewed very quickly, and is now they are just deciding if it should be published.

Answer (score 0):

AE means it is awaiting associate editor recommendation. I got my paper rejected within two days after that. We asked them to reconsider, and they accepted our appeal. Now it is again AE. Fingers crossed.